# Why is row-access high when comparison, order, limit for PK in mysql's query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, row, explain

In this example, id is pk.

And the total number of rows is 541.

In the first example below, all rows with `id > 50` are accessed, but because of `limit 5`, the
`rows` value is expected to be 5. What's the problem?

The `order by` column is pk, and the `where comparison` column is also pk.

=======

`explain select * from mytable where id > 50 order by id limit 5;`

| select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | **rows** | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIMPLE | cpc_pre_booking |  | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 |  | **491** | 100 | Using where |

`explain select * from mytable where id > 200 order by id limit 5;`

| select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIMPLE | cpc_pre_booking |  | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 |  | **341** | 100 | Using where |

`explain select * from mytable where id > 400 order by id limit 5;`

| select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIMPLE | cpc_pre_booking |  | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 |  | **141** | 100 | Using where |

I want to know what am i missing

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause restricts the number of rows _returned by the select_, and not what is filtered by the query. So in the first example 541-50 is 491 rows because of the `WHERE` clause filter, but after that processing the `LIMIT` will only return the first 5 rows. Similar situation for the other two examples.

Answer (score 1):

The "Rows" in `EXPLAIN` are estimates based on statistics, and usually *without* taking into account `LIMIT` value.  Don't trust them very far.

After the fact, the slowlog will provide exact "Rows_examined" and "Rows_returned".

Here's a another way (also by actually running the query):

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```